# Does a constant transition intensity mean that every transition between states increases as time increases?

Tags: statistics, stochastic-processes, markov-process

I'm struggling to understand what one of the key assumptions of a Markov survival model. There are three key assumptions stated:

Take for example a simple HSD model (Where state 1 denotes healthy, state 2 denotes Sick and state 3 denotes dead), $x$ in the subscript denotes the age of the individual being observed.

1) The probability of death in a short period of time $\hat{t} \approx \phi_{x+t}^{12}*\hat{t}$ (For $\phi_{x+t}^{12}$ denoting the transition intensity between states 1 and 2)

2)Markov Property

3) For some t, where $0\leq t\leq1$, constant transition intensity is assumed. This means that $\phi_{x+t}^{12} = \phi_{x}^{12}$, for some integer age $x$.

I read that as a result of this third assumption, as you view increasing ages, the force increases each year. ( $\phi_{x}^{12} < \phi_{x+1}^{12} <...<\phi_{x+n}^{12},  n\in \mathbb{Z}^{+}) $.

My question is, does making this assumption  (3) mean that for other transitions (say $\phi_x^{21}$), the same would occur? And I ask if there is an underlying issue with this because I am curious whether this means if you have a state where clearly the opposite will happen ( $\phi_{x}^{ab} > \phi_{x+1}^{ab} >...>\phi_{x+n}^{ab}$), you are making the assumption that the opposite happens in the case of this Markov Survival model...

Comment: What does $\phi_x$ denote? A transition rate between states would necessarily need to specify two states.

Comment: Hi, say $\phi_x$ acts as notation for $\phi_x^{12}$ for example. The transition rate from state 1 to state 2 in this specific model. My issue is does this assumption with the Markov survival model, mean that this transition (say the transition from having cancer to being healthy), increase year by year if this assumption holds. The assumption is that for some time less than one, we assume a constant transition rate between integer ages. (The x denotes the age of the individual).

Comment: Proposing a bounty prevents the votes to close the question as unclear while the bounty lasts -- but it does not make that the question stops being unclear.

Comment: @Did , I have changed question - I hope it makes more sense what I am trying to ask.

Comment: Not really. Do you have a source for this?

Comment: What is incorrect - the assumptions or my understanding of them (I can understand that the latter is definitely the case). I should say that my understanding of  the line 'hence the force is constant throughout each age, and also increases each year' is  this: ($\phi_{x}^{12} < \phi_{x+1}^{12} <...<\phi_{x+n}^{12},  n\in \mathbb{Z}^{+}) $. But that could be completely wrong.

Comment: So, you have no source for this, thus you probably concocted it all by yourself with no reference to the well established body of knowledge about Markov processes. This is not de facto a problem in itself but this suggests you should beware of the difficulties that you might meet, to be understood by others. Since you do not, the question is stalling.

Comment: It is from the ActEd notes relating to Survival models. "When assuming a constant force of mortality between integer ages, you in turn assume a step-wise increase of the force of mortality each year". I want to know if this assumption for a simple healthy->dead model is true in more complex cases (ie more transition rates). I understand that this assumption may not be true for all Markov models...